# I need to prevent the translation of admin + toobar interface

Tags: i18n-l10n

Hello I am using Internationalization module. I want to keep the admin and the toolbar in English despite the language variable, despite the node translation operation. Is it possible?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [Administration Language](https://drupal.org/project/admin_language) module:

> This module lets the administrator see all administration pages in her preferred language.
>
> You can use this to display the frontend of the site in one language and still keep most of the backend in English (or another language of your choice).
>
> You can use the standard Languages page to choose the language of the admin pages.

Comment: Thanks. What about the core Toolbar menu?

Comment: That should have been be supported from the get go

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have been doing alot of research to change the admin menu language to English this was what worked for me

First install the module "Admin Languages"  https://www.drupal.org/project/admin_language

Second go to [site-domain]/admin/config/regional/language/admin_language and make sure you select the radio button 'Use administration language on every page except the listed pages' and make sure nothing is added in the below text box 
that would stop the user interface getting translated in the entire site

[image]

*when you configure it like this the default language is what will apply all over you can change that too by going here [site-domain]/admin/config/regional/language